# Devise after_sign_in_path with custom sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How to define Devise after_sign_in_path to redirect to page user was before clicking to sign in? I've tried with this in the application_controller:

```
 13   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
 14     sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'new', :controller => 'my_sessions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')
 15     if request.referer == sign_in_url
 16       super
 17     else
 18       stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || request.referer || root_path
 19     end
 20   end
```

With this I only get redirected to root_path. It is worth mentioning that I have custom controller for Sessions callse MySessionsController. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell which branch of the `if` statement is being executed?

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to touch `after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)` since this is the default behaviour.

The return path is stored in `session["user_return_to"]` (if user is your devise scope), and is set by [`store_location!` in `FailureApp`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L175)

this failure app is called each time warden authentication fails: see [warden config](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L415) calling [`Delegator`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/delegator.rb).

is it possible you somehow bypass some of this?

this happens if you warden-authenticate without the bang. warden only bails via the failure app if you call `warden.authenticate!`, see [warden wiki](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/overview) which does happen [if you call devise's `authenticate_user!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L48)

make sure you do use `after_sign_in_path_for` as redirect location in your session controller [like here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L18) in case you have a custom one.

Comment: could it be that I bypass it because of my custom my_sessions controller?

Comment: nope. I get such a funny behavior. Example. I navigate to locations_path. Click on Sign in and I sign in with valid info. Than I get rerouted to new_location_path. I know this is a longshot but can you figure out something from the info I just wrote here?